# C# 9.0 records - non-nullable reference types and constructor

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

I tried just a simple record:

```
#nullable enable

public record Product
{
    public readonly string Name;
    public readonly int CategoryId;
    public readonly string Phone;
    public readonly Address Address;
    public readonly Manager Manager;
}
```

I get warnings:

> Non-nullable property 'Name' is uninitialized. Consider declaring the property as nullable.
>
> *(same for all fields except CategoryId)*

Basically, if I understand correctly, a constructor accepting and setting all fields is *not* auto-generated by the compiler and (when using `#nullable enable`) I have to write it myself, i.e.:

```
public Product(string Name, int CategoryId, string Phone, Address Address, Manager Manager) {
  this.Name=Name;
  this.CategoryId=CategoryId;
   ...
}
```

My question is, is this correct? I am very surprised by this as I thought the whole point was to make creating records like that really simple, and having to write/maintain the constructor is very tedious, especially on big records that change often.
Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Why don't you properly declare those as `init` properties instead of public readonly fields?

Comment: Since you make those properties `readonly` you have to initialize them. And the compiler does not magically know how you want that to be done.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto using init properties doesn't change the warnings,

Comment: @juergend removing readonly doesn't change the warning

Comment: Well, if you do `var product = new Product();`, then everything except `CategoryId` will be `null`, and you have `#nullable enable`, so what do you expect to happen? The compiler is correctly telling you that some properties are not initialized and will be null references

Comment: my expectaion was not having to write this ctor, so that it will auto generate a ctor that has every fields like the one I supplied manually, and also not generate an empty ctor if `#nullable enable`

Comment: I think you don't need to manually generate the ctor (but I could be wrong), but even in that case you can still use `new Product()` so you can still end up with unitialized members. For 9.0, at least, you have to continue writing the ctors if you want `#nullable enable`

Comment: Yeah thats why in this case I expected no default ctor and only a ctor like the one I wrote manually .. I am really surprised its not like that

Comment: The record with nominal properties should require that they all be initialized by any onject initializer expression. However, by using `readonly` you've declared them as fields which may have something to do with it. Record properties were init only by default last time I checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be expecting the auto-generated [Primary Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records#primary-constructor), but it is auto-generated (and in general you get all the record benefits) when you utilize the [record parameters in the record type declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records), which are automatically mapped to [public `get` and `init` properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records#properties) and automatically initialized from the primary constructor, thus eliminating the NRT warning.

Which means that you get all record type sugar by basically using the normal constructor syntax with added `record` keyword:

```
public record Product(string Name, int CategoryId, string Phone, Address Address, Manager Manager) { }
```

Comment: I see, if I try this - see https://sharplab.io/#gist:830bc1e956d87308c739e9b943aeef1a - the properties have `{ get; set; }` not `{ get; init; }` though

Comment: Well, what I wrote by "spec". And what we actually get is by current "preview" implementation. That's why in general I'm against testing/discussing preview things since they could be far from what we'll get with the release. The whole idea of record types is to make them the typed variant of anonymous types. Apparently there is more work to do on these :)

Comment: But I've tried it in the latest preview VS2019, and even though object browser shows them as `get; set;`, the compiler does not allow setting them from outside, so it might be just lacking the `init` metadata.

Comment: For ones who's wondering what "_Primary Constructor_" means, here is explanation - https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/01/CSharp-Primary-Constructors/